# Remove Domain from a URL in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm dissecting urls for SEO purposes and I'm searched all forums for a formula that can remove the domain from a url, but can't seem to find the formula that returns favorable results. This is what I want to do:

https://www.walsallhealthcare.nhs.uk/contact-us/useful-links/subject-categories.aspx

--> **contact-us/useful-links/subject-categories.aspx**

I'm using this formula in Excel to remove domain. However this doesn't work for secured sites, and I always have to replace "8" with "9" to make it work. Is there any way to make this work for both http and https websites?

> =MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,8),LEN(A1)+1-FIND("/",A1,8))

Also, I want to remove the "/" at the beginning. Is this possible?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this with the http and https versions of your URL (where A3 has your URL); seems to work.

```
=RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("/",A3,FIND("//",A3)+2))
```

Comment: Wow! Working smoothly! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating 301 rules, adding a "+1" will make sure the "/" is included in the beginning of the path :

`=RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND("/",A3,FIND("//",A3)+2)+1)`

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to be in excel? You can use google sheets and this simple function will autoextract exactly what you need:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".*\.\w+\/(.*\/*?)")
```

Comment: @pnuts thanks, sorry im still new to this, figuring out where everything is etc :)

Answer (score -1):

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A3;FIND("/";A3;FIND("//";A3)+2)-1);LEN(LEFT(A3;FIND("/";A3;FIND("//";A3)+2)))-FIND("//";A3)-2)
```

If url in A3 field, strips `http://` and `https://` from A3 and returns only domain name without request URI

Comment: Semi-colons in Excel?